# In js2-mode, is there a way to goto the other brace/bracket/paren in the pair?

Tags: js2-mode

eg. if I have

```
{ foo: "bar",
     fu: {"baz": bar}
}
```

And I have my cursor on the last brace, is there a command that will goto the first brace?
Also open to more general packages if there is one that does this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-m-b` (bound to `backward-sexp`) should go to the matching brace at the same level. There are many other useful code navigation commands too: `C-m-f` (bound to `forward-sexp`) and `C-m-u` which goes *up* in the code structure. In combination, these commands are very powerful tools for all sorts of code investigation, as well as editing. And they are available in just about *every* programming language mode.

See [Editing Programs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Programs.html#Programs) in the Emacs manual for much more on this.